# Elegant solution for wall mounted laptops holder

Tags: shelving

I'm looking for an elegant solution to mount laptop holders. I also looked at standard shelves with brackets, but for me it's not much of an elegance.

I have 4 laptops to be displayed on the wall in 2 x 2 configuration (*its for display only to see progress of things from a bit of distance, no humans are standing there to work on them*)

I like this [product](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B079VHSJSB) which is just holder only (*not meant for mounting*) and trying to work my way to mount it somehow to the wall. Each laptop is about 14x10 inches.

I can place two laptops in a row its just I don't like the shelves with brackets too much.

**Any lateral thinking ideas are welcome.**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drill holes in Aluminum laptop holder.

Hold on wall level and mark location on holes on wall.

Use appropriate drill bit to install anchor in wall.

Use appropriate size screw for anchor and a flat washer to mount holder on wall.

Place laptop on holder, stand back and admire laptop and handy DIY work.

If you are mounting 2  ( or 3 or 4 ) laptops all on the same horizontal plane then you mount all of the holders on a nice piece of wood and then mount the board to the wall. This way you can make sure you get the screws  into   studs and you do not need anchors.

[Editors anchor choice](https://www.lowes.com/pd/TOGGLER-10-Pack-Assorted-Length-x-1-4-in-Dia-Toggle-Bolt-Drywall-Anchor-Screws-Included/3183831)